# jruby - Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: jruby

I'm getting an error in jruby that isn't happening in cruby 1.9.3.  Here is the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/4700559 and line of code that is causing the failure https://github.com/dockyard/party_foul/blob/master/lib/generators/party_foul/install_generator.rb#L11 I'm not quite sure how to debug this

Comment: What version of linux are you running and what jre? You are probably running a 64 bit kernel correct?

Comment: This may help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839581/inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-from-fileoutputstream-close/15046511#15046511